# How do you "update" a diretory_iterator after changes to a directory have been made?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-filesystem, boost-iterators

I am writing a program using C++ and Boost::filesystem. The program is supposed to take pictures in a given directory and move them to folders. Each folder is supposed to only hold a given number of pictures.

```
#include<string>
#include<boost/filesystem.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::filesystem;

vector<path> new_folders; //vector of paths that will be used to copy things
//I know a global variable is a bad idea, but this is just a simplified example of my program    

void someFunction(path somePath)
{
  directory_iterator iter(somePath);
  directory_iterator end_iter;

  int count = 0;//used in the naming of folders
  while(iter != end_iter)
  {
    string parentDirectory = iter->path().string(); 
    string newFolder = "\\Folder " + to_string(count+1);

    parentDirectory.append(newFolder);
    path newDir = parentDirectory;

    create_directory(newDir);//create new folder in parent folder
    new_folders.push_back(newDir); //add path to vector

    count++;
    iter++;
  }
}



void fill_folders(path pic_move_from, const int MAXIMUM)
{
  //this iterator does not account for the new folders that were made      
  //-------------------- HERE IS WHERE the problem is located
  directory_iterator iterate(pic_move_from);
  directory_iterator end_iter;

  //fill the new folders with pictures
  for (int folderNum = 0; folderNum < new_folders.size(); folderNum++)
  {
    path newFolder = new_folders.at(folderNum);
    int loopCount = 0; //for the following while loop

    while (loopCount != MAXIMUM && iterate != end_iter)
    {
      if(is_regular_file(*iterate) && img_check(iterate))//item must be a picture to be copied
      { 
        create_copy_multifolder(iterate, newFolder);
      }//end if

      iterate++;
      //the loopCount in the while loop condition should be the max number of folders

      loopCount++;
    }//end while loop
  }//end for loop
}//end fill_folders function


int main()
{
  path myPath = "C:\\Users\\foo";
  const int MAX = 2; //maximum number of pictures per folder

  someFunction(myPath);
  fill_folders(myPath, MAX); 

  return 0;
}
```

The path `pic_move_from` was used in another function. This other function used a directory iterator for this `path`, and in that same function directories were added to the directory referenced by `path pic_move_from`. I tried to make a new iterator for this directory so that I could move any pictures in the directory to the newly added subdirectories. However, the new directory_iterator is not "updated" to work with the new entries in the directory. So, how do you "update" the directory_iterator?

**UPDATE:** I tried to simplify this code as much as possible so I came up with the test/example below. And this example works just fine and prints out the new folder during the second iteration, so I'll have to double check everything in the original code.

```
string pathToFile = "C:\\foo";
path myPath();

directory_iterator iter(pathToFile);
directory_iterator end_iter;

while (iter != end_iter)
{
    cout << endl << iter->path().filename().string() << endl;
    iter++;
}

string pathToNew = pathToFile;
pathToNew.append("\\Newfolderrrrr");
create_directory(pathToNew);

directory_iterator iterate(pathToFile);
directory_iterator end_iterate;

while (iterate != end_iterate)
{
    cout << endl << iterate->path().filename().string() << endl;
    iterate++;
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.  Provide a [MCVE].

Comment: @Yakk I tried to clean it up some.

Comment: Now be less vague.  "in another function" -- if you mean `someFunction` say its name.  Next, *simplify*.  Your code does a lot of stuff; what can you strip out *and still get the same symptoms*.  Ie, skip iterating in `someFunction`, just create *one* new directory.  Problem still occur?  Awesome, case is simpler.  Repeat until you have a really simple case.

Comment: Can you separate the discovery and manipulation? Can you prepare actions before committing?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there was no issue with the directory iterators or how I was using them.

I had another flaw in my code which was strictly a logical error.

The solution was a simple rearrangement of a few blocks of code.

Sorry for all the confusion.